# Botão play reproduz outro áudio

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, áudio

Ttenho uma tabela chamada `posts`, e nela há uma coluna `post_aud` onde é 'inserido um text' com o nome do áudio/música (que é 'salvo' na pasta audios)...

```
$get_posts = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER by 1 DESC";
$run_posts = mysqli_query($db,$get_posts);
while ($row_posts=mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts)){
$post_aud = $row_posts['post_aud'];

<div name='barra'>
  <i id='play' onclick='play();'></i>
  <i id='pause' onclick='pause();'></i>
<audio id='song' >
   <source src='../audios/$post_aud' type='audio/ogg'>
   <source src='../audios/$post_aud' type='audio/mpeg'>
</audio>
```

//javascript

```
function play() {
  document.getElementById('song').play();
}

function pause() {
  document.getElementById('song').pause()
}
```

//fecha javascript

```
</div> //fecha barra
} //fecha while
```

Ou seja, cada post tem o seu post_aud/música, porém, o problema é que toda vez que aperto o play (em qualquer post) ele reproduz apenas o áudio do último post inserido (tanto que se eu utilizo o player normal do html, ele funciona de boa). Alguma ideia do que pode ser??? Grato!!!

Comment: Não seria porque vc tá criando vários elementos com o mesmo id?

Comment: pera, mesma id na tabela?

Comment: Você não pode repetir o código `<audio id='song' >`. Cara player deve ter seu próprio ID. Ex: song1, song2, song3, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está criando vários elementos com o mesmo `id` e criando vários scripts desnecessários no *loop*. O correto seria criar uma contagem `$conta` que seria o uma forma de identificar cada elemento:

```
<?php

$get_posts = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER by 1 DESC";
$run_posts = mysqli_query($db,$get_posts);
$conta = 0;
while ($row_posts=mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts)){
   $post_aud = $row_posts['post_aud'];
?>
<div name='barra<?=$conta?>'>
  <i onclick='play('<?=$conta?>');'></i>
  <i onclick='pause('<?=$conta?>');'></i>

   <audio id='song<?=$conta?>' >
      <source src='../audios/<?=$post_aud?>' type='audio/ogg'>
      <source src='../audios/<?=$post_aud?>' type='audio/mpeg'>
   </audio>
</div>
<?php
   $conta++;
} //fecha while
?>

<script>
function play(id) {
  document.getElementById('song'+id).play();
}

function pause(id) {
  document.getElementById('song'+id).pause()
}
</script>
```

Comment: MEU DEUS, muito obrigado amigo, de verdade mesmo!!!, e nossa, nem tinha visto o lance do script ali kkk, inclusive, esse $conta (contagem), sabe como é em ingles, ou o nome dessa 'função' pra eu procurar um manual a respeito? Grato!!!!

Comment: @Renan De nada amigo! Isso é só uma variável que vai crescendo no loop

Comment: ahhh $conta = 0 e tals... obrigado!! Boa noite xD